# Youtube Content ID API v1 returning 401 error in APIs Explorer

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Any API calls (ex - youtubePartner.assets.get()) is giving 401 error - 
AssetID - ContentID asset's ID
Scope Selected - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Comment: You should contact your YouTube Partner account manager I am sure they can help you.   But invalid credentials means the access token you are sending is wrong or expired.

Comment: Strange that the same token works fine for other YouTube Video API calls but it gives error for partner's API call.

Comment: Because YouTube partners is special you have to have one of that type of account.   If you arnt a YouTube partner you cant use it.   No I don't know how to become one its hard as far as I know.

Comment: Hi, I've got YouTube partner API access so no issue from permission side.

Comment: Contact your youtube account manager if memory serves they need to activate something for you